# Geoserver/Geowebcache producing corrupt tiles

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache

I've used Geoserver 2.6.4 (with GeoWebCache 1.6.2) to generate a tile cache. However, some of the tiles are becoming corrupt (see below). I've looked around and found many references to improvements to GWC that prevent corruption, but they all talk about older versions of GWC that we are using?

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

[image: Corrupt Tile]

EDIT: extra information based on questions:

- If I request the same tile directly using WMS it doesn't have the issue
- The source data is an image mosaic made up of GeoTIFFs (RGB, not palette)
- The data uses the default GeoServer raster style

Comment: please give us some clues, what sort of data? how is it stored? what is the style you applied? what does the log file say? when you turn up debugging?

Comment: Is the problem repeatable if you clear the cache? Does it also show up in WMS? Have you tried upgrading? - 2.6 is out of maintenance support, so if code changes are required, you'll need to upgrade in any case.

Comment: @iant - it's a GeoTIFF image mosaic using the default raster style. I see nothing in the logs related to this.

Comment: @BradHards - If I make the same request (same bbox etc) directly via WMS then it works fine. Unfortunately it's a large cache that is owned by a customer (I don't have the authority to just clear the cache), so that's out of the question for now. I will make the case for upgrading anyway and hope that solves the issue.